# HorizontalScrollView Not Scrolling Completely to the Right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

**My Current Implementation**

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` which I create in XML that houses a few `LinearLayout` children. I have added this code below.

There are two `LinearLayout` containers with the id's `group_one` and `group_two` and these are populated programmatically at run time.

I also fix the width of the `HorizontalScrollView` at run time depending on the amount of `View` objects I will be inserting.

This solution works great for when the children fit in the `HorizontalScrollView` without the need to scroll.

**The Issue**

As soon as I need to scroll (there are more children than can be displayed within the fixed width `HorizontalScrollView`) then the scrollbar will not go all the way to the right, even though I can see that the child layout is of the correct width, and I can see the scrollbar just will not go any further.

**My Question**

Why would there be a limit on the scrollbar moving any further right?

**My Code**

***HorizontalScrollView  XML***

```
<!-- THIS IS WHERE THE PLUGIN BUTTONS ARE HOUSED -->
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/map_plugin_scroll_view"
        android:background="@color/map_plugin_background">

    <!-- Enclosing box to layout the two groups.-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/group_container">

        <!-- These layouts contain the map plugins. -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/group_one"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/group_two"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**What Is Happening**

This is an image of the correct scroll to the left. The edge of the scroll view starts on the right of the red bar. Notice the distance between the two.

[image: Correct Scroll Left]

This is an image of the incorrect scroll right. Compare the distances between the edges of the scroll view and where the scroll bar is stopping.

[image: Incorrect Scroll Right]

This is how I want it to look when I scroll at either end.

[image: Correct Layout]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been playing with this for a while now and finally found the solution.

I was trying to add the left and right margins to the `LinearLayout` with the ID `group_container`. However for some reason the `HorizontalScrollView` was not respecting this and this is why I was seeing this issue.

Instead I added the left and right margins to the `group_one` and `group_two` `LinearLayouts`. Now the `HorizontalScrollView` respected these and it functions as I expected. Here is my modified code.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/map_plugin_scroll_view"
        android:background="@color/map_plugin_background">

        <!-- Enclosing box to layout the two groups.-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/group_container">

            <!-- These layouts contain the map plugins. -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/group_one"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/group_two"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Omg, I was close to loose my head with `ScrollView`, I never expected that there are a `HorizontalScrollView`...

Answer (score 0):

set padding right to your scrollview like this :

```
android:paddingRight="20dp"
```

Comment: This just adds a gap between the content of the child and the scroll view. Still seeing the same issue